# How to determine size of images available in aws?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I'm using one of the images listed here https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md, to create an sagemaker endpoint, but I keep getting "failed reason: Image size 15136109518 is greater that suppported size 1073741824" .

is there a way to find out the size of images provided https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md or any aws managed images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to deploy a serverless endpoint provisioned with 1GB of memory. As discussed [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QU35dVp2D9SKKUnnVYGw9Z7A/how-to-check-determine-image-container-size-for-aws-managed-images) "You can increase the memory size of your endpoint with the MemorySizeInMB parameter, more info in this documentation: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints-create.html#serverless-endpoints-create-config"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints-create.html#serverless-endpoints-create-config%22)

In order to view the uncompressed size of an image you can use the following example command:

```
$ docker pull 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-training:1.15.2-cpu-py27-ubuntu18.04

$ docker inspect -f "{{ .Size }}" 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-training:1.15.2-cpu-py27-ubuntu18.04
```

Kindly also note that you will need to provision enough memory to accommodate your model as well. Please see this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html#serverless-endpoints-how-it-works-memory) for more information.